# How can I apply a color matrix to a raw image in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What do I need to do to apply a 3x3 color transformation matrix to a raw image in unity?

P.S I am using Unity 19.4.0f1

Comment: When you say Image, do you mean Unity's UI Image object, which has a Sprite which uses a Texture? Or do you mean something else? Textures have `GetPixels()` and `SetPixels(...)` which you could use to get the pixel content, transform it, and put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you should know:

- Color can be [implicitly converted to Vector4](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-operator_Color.html) and vice versa
- Vector4 can be transformed with a [Matrix4x4](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4-operator_multiply.html)

So, psuedocode:

```
public Matrix4x4 ColorTransform

pixels = GetPixels
foreach pixel in pixels
    pixel = ColorTransform * pixel
next

SetPixels(pixels)
```

Also note that this allows for transforming Alpha as well.